# How can I have array stored inside of array in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

My issue is, I have an exercise that asks to create 3 classes:

Song(to create and set songs) 
Playlist(to create and add songs to it)
MusicCollection(to have a collection of playlists) now this class is tricky, I need to have a master `library` playlist in the playlists collection that will contain every song in the collection...

So, from what I saw some people define in the MusicCollection property of type Playlist that called library, and in the initialization they do:

```
-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) theName  
{  
    self = [super init];  

    if (self) {  
        musicCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
        library = [[Playlist alloc] initWithName: @"library"];  
        [musicCollection addObject: library];  
    }  
    return self;  
}
```

From what I understand from this, everytime user initialize a collection, so a playlist object will be added to the collection array...

And the problem is that in the addPlaylist method to a collection, they did not add this playlist songs to the library...like this:

```
-(void) addPlaylist: (Playlist *) thePlaylist  
{  
    if ([musicCollection containsObject: thePlaylist] == NO)  
        [musicCollection addObject: thePlaylist];  
}
```

Any thoughts? im really stuck with this :/

I though maybe having the library to by an array inside the collection array and iterate through it to look if the songs are in the library, and if not to add them..

Now, in the Playlist.m the addsong method is:

```
-(void) addSong:(Song *)theSong  
{  
    [playList addObject:theSong];  
}
```

but I see that in the MusicCollection.m they added a method to add songs that adding songs to the library:

```
-(void) addSong: (Song *) theSong toPlaylist: (PlayList *) thePlaylist  
{  
    if([thePlaylist.playList containsObject:theSong]==NO)  
        [thePlaylist addSong:theSong];  

    if([library.playList containsObject:theSong]==NO)  
        [library addSong:theSong];  

}
```

But what if i create a Playlist and just add it to a MusicCllection? without adding songs through the MusicCollection method to add songs..

Comment: Do you have some code where you add a Song to a Playlist?

Comment: yes, please check out the code i added to the question. thanks @SteveO'Connor

Answer (score 0):

For object comparison to work

```
-(void) addPlaylist: (Playlist *) thePlaylist  
{  
    if ([musicCollection containsObject: thePlaylist] == NO)  
        [musicCollection addObject: thePlaylist];  
}
```

you must override `isEqual:` method in `PlayList`

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)other {

    if (other == self)
        return YES;

    if (!other || ![other isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        return NO;

    return [self isEqualToPlayList:other];

}

 //Assuming playListId is an unique identifier in `PlayList`
- (BOOL)isEqualToPlayList:(PlayList*)playList{

    if (self == playList)
        return YES;

    if (self.playListId != playList.playListId)
        return NO;
    //If you you a combinational uniqueness, check for them as well

    return YES;

}
```

For more info follow the object comparison in following [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html)